# Optimize the Weight of a layer while training CNN

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a neural network whose last layer like this,

```
add_5_proba = Add()([out_of_1,out_of_2,out_of_3,out_of_4,  out_of_5 ])
# Here I am adding 5 probability from 5 different layer
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=add_5_proba)
```

But now I want to give weight to them ,Like

```
[a * out_of_1, b* out_of_2, c * out_of_3, d * out_of_4, e * out_of_5]
```

and `optimize the weights (a,b,c,d,e) during training`. How can I do that ? My idea is Using custom Loss
function it can be done, but I have no idea how to implement this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just create `tf.Variables`:

```
a = tf.Variable(1.)
b = tf.Variable(1.)
c = tf.Variable(1.)
d = tf.Variable(1.)
e = tf.Variable(1.)
add_5_proba = Add()([a * out_of_1, b * out_of_2, c * out_of_3, d * out_of_4, e * out_of_5 ])
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=add_5_proba)
```

These variables are trainable by default - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable. They should be optimized during training.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I want to `initialize a weight and optimize during training`. How can I optimize that ?

Comment: @backloggiash see the edited answer